# blah.com works, www.blah.com doesn't

Tags: dns, ip-address, nameserver, cname

I've found many a common question but unfortunately none of them really directly answered my inquiry, below is a copy paste of the info I am provided by [xname.org](http://www.xname.org/) I've replaced my `.com` with `blah.com`, my email with `blah.yahoo.com`, and my IP address with `42.42.42.42`.

```
    $TTL 86400 ; Default TTL
    blah.com.       IN  SOA ns0.xname.org.  blah.yahoo.com. (
                    2013042110  ; serial
                    10800   ; Refresh period
                    3600    ; Retry interval
                    604800  ; Expire time
                    10800   ; Negative caching TTL
                )        

    $ORIGIN blah.com.
                IN      NS      ns1.xname.org.
                IN      NS      ns0.xname.org.
                IN      NS      ns2.xname.org.
                IN      MX  10  blah.com.
    blah.com.           IN      A       42.42.42.42




    www.            IN      CNAME       blah.com.
```

So `blah.com` works but `www.blah.com` doesn't. I initially tried to put just plain `www` for the cname, but found some reference to adding the trailing dot to it. The other uncertainty I have is whether the `blah.com` in "x in cname `blah.com`" should have its trailing dot or not.

I know this should be obvious, and perhaps even easy but I cannot find an answer to this anywhere, I did find some solutions suggesting I put `www.blah.com` as an A listing pointing to my IP but if I can help it I'd prefer only have my IP listed once as it's a dynamic IP and the fewer places I need to update it when it changes the better.

Comment: You've added the domain.com. with the dot on the end which is fine but as far I I'm lend to believe there should be no dot after www have you tried removing it?

Comment: Yes, my initial setup didn't have the dot after the www and still would not resolve for `http://www.blah.com/`

Comment: When you DIG or NSLOOKUP www.blah.com, what is returned? Is it possible it is resolving to the correct IP but the webserver isn't responding to that alias?

Comment: So when I try to resolve the ip of blah.com it works, but www.blah.com it doesn't..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally managed to resolve this after playing with many things, what finally did it was adding:

```
                IN      MX  10  www.blah.com.
```